# Using third party libraries (MxGraph) in angular 4, without installing them from npm

Tags: angular, mxgraph

Can i use third parties libraries such as MxGraph in angular 4 without installing them via npm, as in just placing them maybe in asset folder and referring to them from code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Why wouldn't you ? You just point to the mxClient.js file the good old way